# Integrate $\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{y^2}^{4}{y\cos(x^2)dxdy}}$

Tags: calculus

I'm asked to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{y^2}^{4}{y\cos (x^2)dxdy}}$. Letting $f(x)=\cos (x^2)$ We have have that $\int_{y^2}^{4}{\cos (x^2)dx} = F(4)-F(y^2)$ by the FTC. This gives us

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2}{\int_{y^2}^{4}{y\cos(x^2)dxdy}} &= \int_{0}^{2}{(yF(4)-yF(y^2))dy}\\
&=2F(4)-\int_{0}^{2}yF(y^2)dy\\
&=2F(4)-(\frac{y^2}{2}F(4) \big|_0^2 - \int_{0}^{2}{\frac{y^2}{2} \cdot 2y \cdot f(y^2)dy})\\
&= \int_{0}^{2}{y^3\cos(y^4)dy} = \frac{\sin(16)}{4}
\end{align*}

Is this a valid way to evaluate this integral? The solution given to me changed the order of integration instead and did it a bit differently. Thanks.

Comment: The integration-by-parts looks to be correct.  You are fortunate that the terms involving $ \ F(4) \ $ cancel; this would have been somewhat challenging otherwise.  Generally, most folks would do the integral with the other order of integration to avoid dealing with an unknown anti-derivative function, as **Ganymede** and your provided solution did.

Comment: Yeah, before checking the solution I figured the problem was written for them to cancel out, but with changing order you don't have to worry about that at all.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Switch the order is better: $I = \int_{0}^ 4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} y\cos(x^2)dydx$

Comment: Yeah that's what my solution manual says. I was just wondering if my way was valid since I arrive at the same answer.

Comment: I figured. Does a function need to have an elementary antiderivative in order for me to use the FTC? That's what I was kind of unsure about specifically.

Comment: To use the FTC, you would only need to establish that $ \ f(x) \ $ is continuous over the region of integration, which is safe to say for $ \ \cos(x^2) \ $ .